# What is the meaning of "T" symbol address = 0 in nm output

Tags: nm, multiple-definition-error

I have 2 static libraries, that were compiled differently. At this point, I don't understand the difference.

I just want to understand, for the same symbol in one library, the address of the symbol is 0. And in the other differs from zero. What does it mean?

```
$ nm works/libdriver.a | grep mbedtls_cipher_setup
0000000000000487 T tls_cipher_setup

$ nm not_works/libdriver.a | grep mbedtls_cipher_setup
0000000000000000 T tls_cipher_setup
```

What will be the difference when the linker would use these libraries for linkage?

In my case, if I use works/libdriver.a library, the linkage passes successfully.
But when I use not_works/libdriver.a library, the same linkage generates multiple-definition errors, and the symbol tls_cipher_setup is one of many that generates this error.